# Custom Add to Cart button - Change product description/title

Tags: magento2

I have a simple product in my Magento 2, also I have many landing pages in different domains that are external from Magento platform and all of them has a Button "Buy now" that I want to direct to my shopping cart.

So far I think so is not too complicated, however, I want to customize the name of the item to add to shopping cart, is it possible? How to do it? Is there any hidden field that I could change the name of the product?

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify please? I'm not sure what you mean by change the name of the product to add to the shopping cart. If you just want to change the name of a product this is done in the admin (products > catalog), but I suspect there is more to your questions than that.

Comment: Yes. Let's say I have a product in my catalog called "Galaxy S4" but I want to customize/change it to "Galaxy S4 Adventure" as an external "add to shopping cart" button in my marketing landing pages.